# Please help me with API interface of google maps in google sheet

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-sheets

I am trying to get the distance between two locations in google using google Maps direction API through the script.

However, following [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yftN6gOsW0&t=472s) and researching on my own in [google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start).

I am not able to resolve errors in my following code.

Error

> "Cannot read property 'legs' of undefined"

```
 function GT() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss1 = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mapsheet = ss1.getActiveSheet();
  var start = mapsheet.getRange('B1').getValue;
  var end = mapsheet.getRange('B2').getValue();

  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setOrigin(start)
    .setDestination(end)
    .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING)
    .getDirections();
  var routes = directions.routes[0]

  mapsheet.getRange('A6:D10').clear();

  var nextrow = mapsheet.getLastRow() +1 ;
  const ro = directions.routes[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    
    var ea = ro.legs[1].end_address;
    var sa = ro.legs[1].start_address;
    var distance = ro.legs[1].distance.text;
    var duration = ro.legs[1].duration.text;

    mapsheet.getRange(nextrow,1).setValue(sa);
    mapsheet.getRange(nextrow,1).setValue(ea);
    mapsheet.getRange(nextrow,1).setValue(distance);
    mapsheet.getRange(nextrow,1).setValue(duration);


  }
```

Comment: Well, that's the reason I love coding ...

Comment: Hi Navneet, was your issue solved?

Comment: Yes, with couple of more modifications I was able to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

You forgot the `()` when retrieving the value for `start`:

```
var start = mapsheet.getRange('B1').getValue;
```

Therefore, your are retrieving the method [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue), and not the cell value.

Because of this, `ro` is `undefined` (the origin has to be a string corresponding to an address) and, therefore, you cannot retrieve its `legs` property.

#### Solution:

Add the `()` for `getValue()`:

```
var start = mapsheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
```

This should fix your issue, assuming that cells `B1` and `B2` contain proper addresses.